# Prove/Disprove (alphabet, languages, subset)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following, but am having some trouble.

For all $Z \subseteq \Sigma^*$, $ZZ \subseteq Z$, where $\Sigma$ is some alphabet.

For all $Z \subseteq \Sigma^*$, $Z \subseteq ZZ$, where $\Sigma$ is some alphabet.

Here I believe that $ZZ$ is simply the concatenation of $Z$ with $Z$ so for the first one if we say the set $Z$ contains $(a,b,c)$, then $ZZ$ would be $(aa,ab,ac, ba,bb,bc,ca,cb,cc)$ and as such $ZZ$ is not a subset of $Z$. Is my reasoning correct?

Also using the same reasoning would the second one also be false.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you’ve done is fine. You could simplify it by taking $Z=\{a\}$, so that $ZZ=\{aa\}$; clearly neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: Okay thank you. Since this is a rather simple problem I'll just delete it so it doesn't accumulate since I think there are several similar posts. Or maybe you can delete it so they aren't duplicates everywhere. Sorry I'm relatively new to this site.

Comment: @tclaire, it's fine. Worthless questions get deleted by the crowd here. Not your case at all.